# Is there a command in Rails that installs all your gems and dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependencies

I am learning Ruby on Rails and I find it annoying having to install and worry about gems and other dependencies for the apps I build . Does Rails have a way to install all your gems and dependencies for you ?

Comment: Even an intro level tutorial would have told you this if you had read it

Comment: Of course I know that. My question should have been how to know exactly which gems to use ? If there is a shortcut that gets me all the gems you need or if I should learn and know the specific gems.

Comment: No, there isn't anyone who will build your app for you. You need to know which components to use and how to make them function together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have a file called `Gemfile` in the directory of your application.

Put all the gem you want to use in it.

And then just run `bundle install` to install all in one time (with dependencies) and later `bundle update` to update all your gem installed.

You can see [Bundler: The best way to manage a Ruby application's gems](http://bundler.io/) and [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app#sec-planning_the_application) for more informations.

Comment: I would recommend running `bundle install` the first time around.

Comment: I know this already. I guess my question should have been:"how to know exactly which gems to use ?" Is there a shortcut that gets me all the gems I need or if I should learn and know the specific gems.

Comment: No, no one can know for you what your application does or needs. You have to choose and use a gem only if you need it. For example, do you need pagination? Do you need file upload? Do you need nested forms? Do you need authentication? and so on...

Comment: Great, you have answered my question

Comment: @MoussaSarr If you wish, to indicate that, you can accept my answer.